# How to get max date of previous year in a dataset with a window-function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

I have a simple table with just a DATETIME filed.

My question is, how can I get the value related to the end-of-year of previous year, with a window-function query?

I've tried with this query but the result is the end-of-year of the current year:

```
SELECT datefield, max(datefield) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(datefiled)) FROM foo
```

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter records then you need to use `Where` clause. You need something like this not window function.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties *
FROM   foo
WHERE  datefield <= Datefromparts(Year(Getdate()) - 1, 12, 31)
ORDER  BY datefield DESC
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   foo
WHERE  datefield = (SELECT Max(datefield) AS last_date_prev_year
                    FROM   foo
                    WHERE  datefield <= Datefromparts(Year(Getdate()) - 1, 12, 31))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use a windowed function.  A simple filter combined with the [max function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will return the end of the previous year.

```
-- Where clause removes records from current and future years.
SELECT 
    MAX(datefield)
FROM
    foo
WHERE
    YEAR(datefield) < YEAR(GETDATE())
;
```

Although simple, this approach has a small problem.  Using the [year function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx), on `datefield` in the where clause, makes the query [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).  If performance is an issue; you could fix by using [DateFromParts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) as demonstrated in @Prdp's fine answer.

**EDIT**

This version of the query uses a windowed function, as requested by the OP.

```
-- Max of previous year, using a windowed function.
SELECT
    MAX(datefield) AS LastYearEnd
FROM
    (
        -- Rank records based on year.
        -- Current year is 1, last year is 2, etc.
        SELECT
            datefield,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(datefield) DESC) AS rn
        FROM
            foo
    ) AS dr
WHERE
    rn = 2
;
```

The above only returns one record.  If you want see the last day of the previous year, next to every record in your table:

```
-- Returns last day of previous year, relative to dateField.
SELECT
    datefield,
    DATEADD(YEAR, -1, MAX(datefield) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(datefield)))
FROM
    foo
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my goal is to achieve the result with a windowed function. I have no performance issues, just a simple query design question

Comment: I've added two new examples.  I think the second is probably closest to what you want.  It is basically your query, combined with the [dateadd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186819.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function.